# Range function in python

Tags: python, range

```
for n in range(2,5):
    for x in range(2,n):
        print(n,x)
```

Gives output as:

```
3 2
4 2
4 3
```

why the value of n start from 3 not 2?

Comment: Because, `range(2, 2)` is an empty range so it'll be skipped.

Answer (score 6):

`n` starts at three because `range(2, 2)` is empty.  Maybe you really want:

```
for n in range(2, 5):
    for x in range(2, n + 1):
        print(n, x)
```

#### Results:

```
2 2
3 2
3 3
4 2
4 3
4 4
```